# Get number in every month of every year using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL query that counts the number of Incoming collaborator every month for year passed on parameter.

I would like to get Incoming collaborator for all the years by month.

This is my sql query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(collaborateur.DATE_ENTREE) AS nbrEntre , a.mnt,a.yr
          FROM (
SELECT  01 as  mnt,2013 as yr  
 UNION 
SELECT 02 as mnt ,2013 as yr  
UNION
 SELECT 03 as mnt,2013 as yr  
UNION
 SELECT 04 as mnt,2013 as yr   
UNION 
SELECT 05 as mnt,2013 as yr  
UNION 
SELECT 06 as mnt,2013 as yr  
 UNION 
SELECT 07 mnt,2013 as yr  
UNION
 SELECT 08 as mnt,2013 as yr  
 UNION
 SELECT 09 as mnt,2013 as yr   
 UNION 
SELECT 10 as mnt,2013 as yr   
UNION 
SELECT 11 as mnt,2013 as yr  
 UNION 
SELECT 12 as mnt,2013 as yr    
 ) 
as a left join  collaborateur on a.mnt=MONTH( collaborateur.DATE_ENTREE)  and a.yr=DATE_FORMAT(collaborateur.DATE_ENTREE, "%Y")  GROUP by YEAR(collaborateur.DATE_ENTREE), MONTH(collaborateur.DATE_ENTREE)
```

Comment: And you are not satisfied with your query? Why? How is its result different from what you want?

Comment: thanks for your reply :i want a query thas gets results for all years not just on 2013

Answer (score 0):

You could change your union query over to something like:

```
(
    SELECT month, year
    (
        SELECT 1 as month
        UNION SELECT 2
        UNION SELECT 3
        UNION SELECT 4
        UNION SELECT 5
        UNION SELECT 6
        UNION SELECT 7
        UNION SELECT 8
        UNION SELECT 9
        UNION SELECT 10
        UNION SELECT 11
        UNION SELECT 12
    ) months,
    (
        SELECT 2000 as year
        UNION SELECT 2001
        UNION SELECT 2002
        UNION SELECT 2003
        UNION SELECT 2004
        UNION SELECT 2005
        UNION SELECT 2006
        UNION SELECT 2007
        UNION SELECT 2008
        UNION SELECT 2009
        UNION SELECT 2010
        UNION SELECT 2011
        UNION SELECT 2012
        UNION SELECT 2013
        UNION SELECT 2014
        UNION SELECT 2015
        UNION SELECT 2016
        UNION SELECT 2017
    ) years
) as a
```

This will cross join each month with each year and spit out a big derived table of every combination. Essentially all years and all months from 2000 to 2017.

You might find it best though to just create a table of dates or month/years so you don't have to haul this beast out every time you want a sequence of month/years.

Comment: Ah, that's what's being asked? Nowadays (i.e. for the last 25 years) we would write `CROSS JOIN` rather than `,` by the way.

Comment: OP said they are passing the year in by parameter. I agree it would have been best to write "I need to do this for all years, but writing 12*number_of_years union queries would be painful".

Comment: thanks again , the problem that i want to get results for all years knowing that i have a column called date_entree so :  get results by month for all years saved in column date_entree